# spinner not being called on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript to validate a form - called theForm - and also to show a spinner after the form is validated and submitted. method is POST and ACTION to a separate page. Validation works but I can't get the spinner to work. Am I able to call both scripts on clicking submit button?

the javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">        
 $(function() {

 $('#theForm').on("submit", function () {

    setTimeout(function () {

          $('#loading').show();

    }, 100);

  });
  });

 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">    

 function validateRegForm()
{

var emailfield=document.forms["theForm"]["email"].value;
if (emailfield==null || emailfield=="")
{
alert("Please enter your email address");
return false;
}

if (confirmemailaddress==null || confirmemailaddress=="")
{
 alert("Please confirm your email address");
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

and then the hidden div:

```
 <div id="loading" style="display:none;
    background: url('hand_timer4.gif') no-repeat 5px 3px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    z-index:1000" >


  <div style="position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; width:600px; overflow-y:auto;     
  height:400px; margin-top: -200px; margin-left: -300px; font-size:12px;    
   text-align:center; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px; 
  color:black">
    <img src="images/hand_timer4.gif" alt="loading" /><br><br>
        <p>Your account is being created. Please be patient...</p>  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Because the form loads a new page. Instead you need to ajax the content. Also I would return true at the end of the validation. How does the form tag look like? I guess you have an onsubmit there too?

Comment: there's a difference between java and javascript

Comment: Yeah, I have onsubmit calling the validateRegForm() script in form tag

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you load jQuery?
2. Do you already have an inline onsubmit for the validation
3. The submission of a form loads a new page and unloads the current page. You may want to consider AJAX

Here is a cleaner way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>        

<script type="text/javascript">        
$(function() {

  $('#theForm').on("submit", function () {

    var emailfield=$("#email"].val(); // assuming the field has an ID
    if (emailfield=="") {
      alert("Please enter your email address");
      return false;
    }
    var confirmemailaddress=$("#confirmemailaddress"].val(); // assuming the field has an ID
    if (confirmemailaddress=="" ||emailfield != confirmemailaddress) {
      alert("Please confirm your email address");
      return false;
    }
    $('#loading').show();
    return true;
  });
});
</script>
```